# PHP - Array name out of variables

Tags: php

Is it possible to use php variable as a part of an array name. like this
my arrays are Fday1, Fday2....but i cant go with the foreach keys beacause there are different counts of values for each array

```
$FdayArray = "Fday".$FdayKey;
array_push($FdayArray, $forecast);
```

the FdayKey would be a number between 1-9 
How do I do this correctly?

Comment: What you expecting result?

Comment: Can you explain your problem further? What is `$forecast`? Is there any reason not to use `$$FdayArray`?

Comment: Why not use one array to wrap around all your arrays? That way it will all be contained inside a coutable and loopable array that will surely be easier than a dynamic number of arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the [`variable variables`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) feature of php.

> Sometimes it is convenient to be able to have variable variable names.
>   That is, a variable name which can be set and used dynamically. It
>   takes the value of a variable and treats that as the name of a
>   variable

You would use

```
array_push($$FdayArray, $forecast);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of maintaining different array for each  `$FdayKey`, you can have an associative array, which  has internal arrays  corresponds to each `$FdayKey`

The array can look like:

```
$FdayArray = [
  '1' => [],
  '2' => [],
  '3' => [],
  '4' => [],
  '5' => [],
  '6' => [],
  '7' => [],
  '8' => [],
  '9' => []
];
```

When you need to push to the array, just use the `$FdayKey`  as a index to get the relevant array.

So you can push as:

```
array_push($FdayArray[$FdayKey], $forecast);
```

Comment: This is a better option. I understand what you mean but maybe you can make it more clear for OP what you mean?

Comment: Good one! I have already upvoted. But if I could I would do it again!